# Regex to match blocks of text containing substrings wrapped in triple square brackets

Tags: php, regex

Given a whole block of text:

> Welcome to [[[RegExr v2.0 by gskinner.com]]]
>
> Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the
>   expression for details. Undo mistakes with ctrl-z. Save & Share
>   expressions with friends or the Community. [[[A full Reference & Help is
>   available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial.
>
> Sample text for]]] testing: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789 _+-.,!@#$%^&*();/|<>"' 12345
>   -98.7 3.141 .6180 9,000 +42
>   555.123.4567  +1-(800)-555-2468 foo@demo.net  bar.ba@test.co.uk www.demo.com

I need a regex that can validate that all open triple square brackets '[[[' in the string are paired up and closed ']]]'. Nested brackets and strings that begin with ']]]' or end with '[[[' should return false.

I know there are ways to loop through the string and evaluate this, but I might be potentially dealing with very large strings of text and was hoping a regex would be faster/better for performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852642/why-does-this-solution-fail-nested-and-matching-brackets You can remove all None-brackets in advance using a regex, then validate the remaining part. With only regex it'll be hard since brackets can be nested (usually)

Comment: What if `]]]` comes before the paired `[[[`? Are they considered paired then?

Comment: I have come up with a [regex for this](https://regex101.com/r/pJ4xL1/1) but its effeciency highly depends on the number of `]`s and `[`s in your files.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with the following solution using the pattern: `/[\[]{3}[^\[\]]*[\]]{3}/`. Unfortunately the third `$text` case will still return false, so I'm working on that. The regex pattern can be seen in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/fS6iY1/1).

```
$text = 'Some [[[default]]] [[[text]]] here'; //valid
//$text = 'Some [[[default text [[[here]]]'; //invalid
//$text = 'Some [[[default text [here]]]'; //invalid

// Get the number of opening and closing brackets
$open_bracket_count = substr_count($text, '[[[');
$close_bracket_count = substr_count($text, ']]]');

// Check if number of '[[[' is same as ']]]'
if ($open_bracket_count === $close_bracket_count)
{
  // Match valid bracketed substrings in the text
  $validation_pattern = '/[\[]{3}[^\[\]]*[\]]{3}/';
  $valid_match_count = preg_match_all($validation_pattern, $text, $valid_matches);

  // Valid matches should equal the number of substrings attempting to be wrapped in brackets
  if ($valid_match_count === $open_bracket_count)
  { 
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
// If not equal, we know right away the string contains invalid brackets
else
{
  return false;
}
```