# Cannot increment variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning how to code, would appreciate any inputs. This is a code I wrote to solve an easy problem on Leetcode.

The problem is that when the first time dict_ab[deck[-1]] == s[i+1], after executing deck.pop(), it'll then iterate i to i +=2. However this is not happening and i automatically only +=1. What is there that I did wrong? I have been working on this for a whole day, couldn't figure it out.

```py
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        a = ('(','{','[')
        b = (')','}',']')
        dict_ab = dict(zip(a,b))

        import collections

        if (len(s) % 2 == 1) or (len(s) == 0):
            return False
        else:
            deck = collections.deque()
            #deck.append(s[0])
            #print(s[0])
            #print(len(s))
            for i in range(0, len(s), 1):
                #print(i)
                deck.append(s[i])
                #print(deck)

                if dict_ab[deck[-1]] == s[i+1]:
                    deck.pop()
                    #print(deck)
                    i +=2
                elif dict_ab[deck[-1]] != s[i+1]:
                    deck.append(s[i])
                    i +=1


            if len(deck) > 0:
                return False

        return True


    s = ('()[]')
    result = Solution().isValid(s)
    print(result)
```

The result I see is as below:

> ```py
>     KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-9-56d864c71658> in <module>()
>      37         return True
>      38 s = ('()[]')
>     ---> 39 result = Solution().isValid(s)
>      40 print(result)
>
>     <ipython-input-9-56d864c71658> in isValid(self, s)
>      23                 print(deck)
>      24 
>     ---> 25                 if dict_ab[deck[-1]] == s[i+1]:
>      26                     deck.pop()
>      27                     print(deck)
>
>     KeyError: ')'
> ```

Comment: More people will see your question if you add the generic `python` tag. But you _need_ to explain what your program is supposed to do. It looks like you're trying to test for matching brackets, or something like that. You get that `KeyError` because there are no closing brackets in the keys of `dict_ab`. You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25854415/4014959) helpful.

Comment: Hi @PM2Ring Thanks for your response! I was trying to not reveal too much info since it is a question on Leetcode. But yes you are correct that the question is asking to find matching parenthesis. I have solved it. I will post the answer here. My original solution as posted here yesterday, did not do the imbricated conditions right and hence it was a problem to execute. (I am adding my corrected solution here -- but I don't know if this is OK -- if it is not, please inform and I'll delete the question and solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a leetcode question. Rated as "Easy".

Given a string containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.
The brackets must close in the correct order, "()" and "()[]{}" are all valid but "(]" and "([)]" are not.

== below is the solution so if you don't want to read it, stop here ==

```
class Solution:
def isValid(self, s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: bool
    """
    a = ('(','{','[')
    b = (')','}',']')
    dict_ab = dict(zip(a,b))

    import collections

    if (len(s) % 2 == 1) or (len(s) == 0):
        return False
    else:
        deck = collections.deque()
        for i in range(0, len(s), 1):
            if s[i] in a:
                deck.append(s[i])
            else:
                if s[i] in b:
                    if len(deck) == 0:
                        return False
                    else:
                        if s[i] == dict_ab[deck[-1]]:
                            deck.pop()
                        else:
                            return False



        if len(deck) > 0:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: There are various improvements that could be made to this code. Don't put `import` statements inside functions or classes, put them at the top of the script. But actually, you don't need a deque here: you only pop from the end, so you can use a plain list. Loop directly over the string instead of using an index, eg `for ch in s:`. You can reduce some of that nesting by using `elif:` instead of `else:if`. Don't test that a list is empty by calling `len`: instead of `if len(deck) == 0` just do `if not deck`.

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring :) yes indeed, I did some improvement on it too (like you pointed out). Appreciate your inputs.